# State doesn't change instantly on button press in different function in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React Native application, i am changing data on previous and next button. Now i have a function called `getImageChunked` where i'm setting the data on state. But on pressing previous button and next button data doesn't change instantly on those button press functions. Instead in button press functions, it shows the previous state data. Here's my current code :

```js
  const [imageSet, setImage] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [nextImage, setNextImage] = useState(false);
  const [prevImage, setPrevImage] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
      getImageChunked();
    },[]);
      
  nextButton = () =>{
        setCount(count + 1);
        getImageChunked(count + 1);
        console.log('imageset',imageSet) // It shows previous state data
        if (props.imageset === []){
          setNextImage(true);
        }
    }

    prevButton = () =>{
        setCount(count - 1);
        getImageChunked(count - 1);
        console.log('imageset',imageSet) // It shows previous state data
        if (props.imageset === []){
          setPrevImage(true);
        }
        
    }

    getImageChunked = (n) =>{
      var perChunk = 4 

      var result = 'API Data'
      var merged = [].concat.apply([], result[n === undefined ? 0 : n]);
      console.log('merged',merged); // Here the data changes properly
      setImage(merged);
    }
```

How i can get instant changed state data on prevButton and nextButton press functions?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, React will queue actions and then execute them in batches at a later time, which can cause these types of lagging state issues

One way to deal with this, is to watch your state with useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getImageChunked()
}, [count])
```

This way, `getImageChunked()` will only be called after your `count` state has updated

Comment: That doesn't actually solve the issue. The problem what i think is happening is imageSet is not updating instantly in nextButton and prevButton function and nextImage and prevImage is always false even if their value is [] @RobbieD

Comment: So the issue is with your `if` statement always failing?

Comment: Yes, actually i need imageSet changed data instantly from getImageChunked function to nextButton or prevButton function. @RobbieD

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible to get the state to update instantly. You'll most likely have to figure out a way to separate the if statement from your button functions so that they don't rely on an instant state change.
Also, you are checking `props.imageset` and not `imageSet` in the if statement, which could be why it's failing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following:

```
  const [imageSet, setImage] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [nextImage, setNextImage] = useState(false);
  const [prevImage, setPrevImage] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
      getImageChunked();
    },[count]); // Each time count is changing getImageChunked got called
      
  nextButton = () =>{
        setCount(count + 1);
        if (Array.isArray(props.imageset)){ // AFAIK props.imageset === [] is always false
          setNextImage(true);
        }
    }

    prevButton = () =>{
        setCount(count - 1);
        if (Array.isArray(props.imageset)){
          setPrevImage(true);
        }
        
    }

    getImageChunked = () =>{
      var perChunk = 4 

      var result = 'API Data'
      var merged = [].concat.apply([], result[count]);
      console.log('merged',merged); // Here the data changes properly
      setImage(merged);
    }
```

Comment: Still not getting imageSet changed data instantly from getImageChunked function to nextButton or prevButton function. I need imageSet data on nextButton or prevButton function to make the condition working properly. @MichaelBahl

Comment: There is no need that this gonna happen instantly, it will happen after next rerender caused by state update.